# How can I keep column titles when using to-matrix?

Tags: clojure, charts, legend, incanter

I tried to do "Principal components analysis" with Incanter today. What I don't have yet, though, is an appropriate legend. I can add a legend, but it's only numbers instead of names.
[in this post](http://data-sorcery.org/category/pca/) from 2010 they show how Incanter keeps the column titles after doing to-matrix, but this seems to have changed, and it doesn't work without using to-matrix.

How can I get a different legend?

Comment: Please post some code so that we can see what you are doing and work from there.

Comment: Just get rid of `to-matrix` in the call of `get-dataset` - matrices are simple matrices, without column titles - use datasets if you want to have ones. I plan to go over the blog, and fix examples (some day)...

Comment: If I remove the `to-matrix` it fails at `(def pca (principal-components X))` at the blog example.

Comment: Yep, I've found this also - I'll try to fix this bug soon